# For loop array in R

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, vector

I am trying to use a 100-point-grid to solve a dynamic programming system, but my array is not changing with each iteration--what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
k_cur<-2
iterations<-100
A<- 4
alpha<-0.3
beta<-0.98
karray<-c(log(A*k_cur^alpha-(alpha*beta*A*(k_cur)^(alpha))))
awesomefunction<-function(iterations){
    for(i in 1:iterations){
          k_prime<-(alpha*beta*A*(k_cur)^(alpha))
          v_cur<-(log(A*k_curr^alpha-k_prime))
          karray<-append(v_cur,karray)
          k_cur<-k_prime
                          }
    print(karray)
    plot(karray)
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think your array is not changing with each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see is that k_cur is misspelled on line 11.
The following ran for me:

```
k_cur<-2
iterations<-100
A<- 4
alpha<-0.3
beta<-0.98
karray<-c(log(A*k_cur^alpha-(alpha*beta*A*(k_cur)^(alpha))))
awesomefunction<-function(iterations){
    for(i in 1:iterations){
          k_prime<-(alpha*beta*A*(k_cur)^(alpha))
          v_cur<-(log(A*k_cur^alpha-k_prime))
          karray<-append(v_cur,karray)
          k_cur<-k_prime
                          }
    print(karray)
    plot(karray)
  }

awesomefunction(4)
```

and produced:
[image: output]

Is that what you were after?